# How to call SBT InputTask dynamically?

Tags: scala, dynamic, sbt

I want to create a new custom `InputTask` (`testOnlyCustom`)

- that calls `testOnly` with the same arguments as given to `testOnlyCustom` and
- that maybe, based on a SBT setting (`condition`), calls another task (let's call it `pre`) **before** calling testOnly. Here, I have to force "sequential" execution.

Thus:

```
If condition is true
  testOnlyCustom com.dummy.TestSuite calls
    pre and then
    testOnly com.dummy.TestSuite

If condition is false
  testOnlyCustom com.dummy.TestSuite calls
    testOnly com.dummy.TestSuite
```

While I was able to achieve a solution with `testCustom` referring to `pre` and `test` (and thus having no arguments), I'm not able to solve the problem for `testOnlyCustom`, as `InputTask` used

Here is my code:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.Def._
import sbtsequential.Plugin._


object Simple extends sbt.Plugin {

  import SimpleKeys._

  object SimpleKeys {
    lazy val condition = SettingKey[Boolean]("mode", "The mode.")

    lazy val pre = TaskKey[Unit]("test-with-pre", "Do some pre step.")

    lazy val testWithPre = TaskKey[Unit]("test-with-pre", "Run pre task beforehand")
    lazy val testCustom = TaskKey[Unit]("test-custom", "Run pre (depending on condition) and then test.")

    lazy val testOnlyWithPre = InputKey[Unit]("test-only-with-pre", "Run selected tests (like test-only in SBT) with pre executed before.")
    lazy val testOnlyCustom = InputKey[Unit]("test-only-configured", "Run pre (depending on condition) and then call test-only.")
  }

  lazy val baseSettings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(

    // this is working
    testWithPre := test.value,
    testWithPre <<= testWithPre.dependsOn( pre ),

    testCustom := Def.taskDyn {
      val c = condition.value

      if (c) {
        testWithPre
      } else {
        test
      }
    }.value,


    //
    // this is the part, where my question focuses on
    //
    testOnlyWithPre := testOnly.evaluated,
    testOnlyWithPre <<= testOnlyWithPre.dependsOn( pre ),

    // is this the correct approach?
    testOnlyCustom := Def.inputTaskDyn {
      // ???????????????????????????????
      Def.task()
    }.evaluated
  )

  lazy val testSimpleSettings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]] = baseSettings
}
```

1. Is `inputTaskDyn` the way to go? What exactly does it? I have just chosen it, because it seems to be dynamic version for `InputTasks`. Unfortunately, documentation is very rare on `inputTaskDyn`.
2. Is it okay to force "sequential" execution via `dependsOn`, like I did? I already have seen tha SBT 0.13.8 contains `Def.sequantial`. But this does not seem to be applicable to InputTasks?
3. How to convert an `InputTask` into a `Task` (to be used with taskDyn / inputTaskDyn) but still sticking to `evaluated` instesd of using an explicit parser? Or is there a way to reuse the `testOnly` parser?
4. Could someone illustrate a little more on `.evaluated` and `.parsed` of `InputTask`. What exactly does `InputTask.parse` do under the hood?

It would be great if someone could provide a working solution!

Many thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Additional comments

**First**, OlegYch_ indicated on Freenode # sbt that coming up with SBT 0.13.9 the execution of `Inputtask`s will be possible via

```
def runInputTask[T](key: InputKey[T], input: String, state: State): (State, T)
```

in `sbt.Extracted.scala`.

**Second**, the testOnly parsers can be reused via `sbt.Defaults#inputTests`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the SBT 1 equivalent is

`testOnlyWithPre := test.dependsOn(pre).value`

and

`testOnlyWithPre := testOnly.dependsOn(pre).evaluated`

Answer (score 0):

the best solution I could come up with is

```
    testOnlyCustom := Def.inputTaskDyn {
      val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("").parsed
      val c = condition.value

      if (c) {
        testOnlyWithPre.toTask(" " + args.head)
      } else {
        testOnly.toTask(" " + args.head)
      }
    }.evaluated
```

But still, this forces me to use a new parser (`spaceDelimited`) and I am not able to (re-)use the testOnly parser.

Any ideas how to reuse the parser?